# Swipe.js bug with IE7

Tags: swipe, internet-explorer-7, swipe.js

Does anyone know how to get swipe.js (http://swipejs.com/) working in IE7?

Despite the claims on the site, I've found that it simply doesn't work. Double checked my code and found that the plugin's own demo fails in IE7.

If anyone knows how this can be fixed it would be a great help.